# How to specify outbound certificate alias for HTTPS-calls?

Tags: java, ssl, https, certificate, keystore

I am calling a webservice that requires client certificate authentication.

If I specify a Java keystore containing a single certificate (the client certificate the service expects) then everything works fine. However if I use a keystore that contains multiple certificates then I can't seem to be able to specify which certificate should be picked up by the client, the client seems to pick up the first available certificate (in alphabetical order).

I have tried the following property but without expected result:

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias", "my-client-certificate alias");
```

How can I specify which client certificate alias that should be used?

Comment: Does the keystore also contain the client's private key, or you have only imported a list of certificates?

Comment: Yes, it contains the clients private key, among other private keys.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: it cannot be done with default Java ssl implementation.

Long answer: I looked on how the SSL handshake is implemented in the `sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker`. In its method `serverHelloDone` is called `X509ExtendedKeyManager.chooseClientAlias`. Its implementations are really done in such a way that they return first alias, whose entry matches the given key algorithm and few other things. No way how to tweak the alias selection.

For those who can change the code, this looks like a promising workaround: http://www.44342.com/java-f392-t785-p1.htm

Comment: I've found link to more sofisticated solution: http://www.angelfire.com/or/abhilash/site/articles/jsse-km/customKeyManager.html

Answer (score 16):

The links that [Jakub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155708/jakub) provides [in his response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5292768/1121673) lead you to the answer, but I wanted to post a simpler response here, since we struggled with this problem for quite a while before finally getting something that worked.

We have the case where there are several certificates available to use, and we need to use the one that has a specific alias to perform our connection. We did this by creating our own KeyManager implementation which passes through most of its functionality to the default X509KeyManager but has functionality to select exactly the correct alias to use when the connection is performed.

First the key manager we created:

```
public class FilteredKeyManager implements X509KeyManager {

private final X509KeyManager originatingKeyManager;
private final X509Certificate[] x509Certificates;

public FilteredKeyManager(X509KeyManager originatingKeyManager, X509Certificate[] x509Certificates) {
    this.originatingKeyManager = originatingKeyManager;
    this.x509Certificates = x509Certificates;
}

public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(String alias) {
    return x509Certificates;
}

public String[] getClientAliases(String keyType, Principal[] issuers) {
    return new String[] {"DesiredClientCertAlias"};
}
```

All other methods required for implementation are passthroughs to `originatingKeyManager`.

Then, when we actually set up the context:

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
context.init(new KeyManager[] { new FilteredKeyManager((X509KeyManager)originalKeyManagers[0], desiredCertsForConnection) },
    trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
```

Hope that makes it clear, and works for anyone else trying to solve this problem.

Comment: If that's of interest, this is what the key manager wrapper does here: http://code.google.com/p/jsslutils/wiki/SSLContextFactory   It should be easy to change the [FixedServerAliasKeyManager](http://code.google.com/p/jsslutils/source/browse/trunk/jsslutils/src/main/java/org/jsslutils/sslcontext/keymanagers/FixedServerAliasKeyManager.java) for use on the client side instead of the server side.

Answer (score 7):

Heres a complete code snipped that works.

I use it to create an SSL connection on Android with a keystore from a smartcard that contains multiple certificates that match the standard filtering criteria.

Credits go to zarniwoop.

```
/**
 * filters the SSLCertificate we want to use for SSL
 * <code>
 * KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
 * kmf.init(keyStore, null);
 * String SSLCertificateKeyStoreAlias = keyStore.getCertificateAlias(sslCertificate);
 * KeyManager[] keyManagers = new KeyManager[] { new FilteredKeyManager((X509KeyManager)kmf.getKeyManagers()[0], sslCertificate, SSLCertificateKeyStoreAlias) };
 * </code>
 */
private class FilteredKeyManager implements X509KeyManager {

    private final X509KeyManager originatingKeyManager;
    private final X509Certificate sslCertificate;
    private final String SSLCertificateKeyStoreAlias;

    /**
     * @param originatingKeyManager,       original X509KeyManager
     * @param sslCertificate,              X509Certificate to use
     * @param SSLCertificateKeyStoreAlias, Alias of the certificate in the provided keystore
     */
    public FilteredKeyManager(X509KeyManager originatingKeyManager, X509Certificate sslCertificate, String SSLCertificateKeyStoreAlias) {
        this.originatingKeyManager = originatingKeyManager;
        this.sslCertificate = sslCertificate;
        this.SSLCertificateKeyStoreAlias = SSLCertificateKeyStoreAlias;
    }

    @Override
    public String chooseClientAlias(String[] keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket) {
        return SSLCertificateKeyStoreAlias;
    }

    @Override
    public String chooseServerAlias(String keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket) {
        return originatingKeyManager.chooseServerAlias(keyType, issuers, socket);
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(String alias) {
        return new X509Certificate[]{ sslCertificate };
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getClientAliases(String keyType, Principal[] issuers) {
        return originatingKeyManager.getClientAliases(keyType, issuers);
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getServerAliases(String keyType, Principal[] issuers) {
        return originatingKeyManager.getServerAliases(keyType, issuers);
    }

    @Override
    public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String alias) {
        return originatingKeyManager.getPrivateKey(alias);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My impression of the KeyManager is that once it is initialized with the keystore, it uses the alias of the private key entry to find the associated certificate and certificate chain.
Otherwise,I think it chooses a chain based on the key types and certificate authorities recognized by the host.
So in your case, your description does not mention a private entry in the keystore, so I will guess that the keymanager chooses the most suitable certificate.
I am not aware at all of the system property you mention.
-Try to change the keystore to have a private key and the associated chain
-Or (not sure if this will work) change the alias of the certificate you want to send to the server to match the subject name of the certificate

Comment: It does contain the private key together with the chain. Using System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl"); I am able to verify that when the KeyStore only contains one entry then it is picked up and everything works fine. Using a KeyStore with multiple private keys the application seems to pick the 1st certificate in the order they appear when you list the entries using keytool-command.

Comment: @aksamit:Multiple private keys?You have in the keystore multiple private keys and their chains?Because from your question I thought you had only multiple certificates (only trusted certificates)