# Jersey Client with SSL Mutual Authentication

Tags: java, ssl, jersey, keytool, jersey-client

Im have a code write in java and im using jersey client and i tried to do a mutual certification, so i also have a .jks that contains my certificates signed by the CA, so this is my code

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@POST
@Path("PruebaPlumaCalva")
public Response testPlumaCalva(String jsonObject)
{
    // ClientBuilder.newClient().
    logger.debug("Test");
    Map<String, Object> payload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    payload.put("documentType", x);
    payload.put("documentNumber", xxxxxx);
    payload.put("partner", "xxx");
    payload.put("transactionId", "xxxxx");

    logger.debug("Mis parametros son:" + payload);
    String json = null;

    try
    {
        json = (new ObjectMapper()).writeValueAsString(payload);
    }
    catch (JsonProcessingException e)
    {
    }

    HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("xxxxx", "xxxx");
    //SSLContext scl = SslConfigurator.newInstance().trustStoreFile("C:/Users/juan.rojas/Documents/Juan José/Proyectos/PagosMoviles/KeyStore.jks").trustStorePassword("123456").keyStoreFile("C:/Users/juan.rojas/Documents/Juan José/Proyectos/PagosMoviles/KeyStore.jks").keyPassword("123456").createSSLContext();
    SSLContext scl = SslConfigurator.newInstance().trustStoreFile("/cdrive/f_drive/Pos.jks").trustStorePassword("123456").keyStoreFile("/cdrive/f_drive/Pos.jks").keyPassword("test").createSSLContext();
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
            .sslContext(scl)
            .build();
    client.register(feature);
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target("xxxxxxxx");
    Invocation.Builder invocationB = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    Response response = invocationB.post(Entity.json(json));
    JsonNode jsonNode = bonusUtilities.createJsonNode(response);
    logger.debug("JsonNode Answer" + jsonNode);
    int x = 0;

    return response;
}
```

So when i execute that code with only 1 certificate he works good, but when i have 2 certificates he dont works, i think that the problem is that the .jks dont know which certicate he must use, but i dont know how to specify which one he must use, i already look a lot of forums but i cant see someone that provides me the solution to my problem

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and could solve it thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8671518/9486436).
Basically, there's no way to do this "out of the box", you have to implement you own KeyManager.

I simplified the linked answer a bit more and the code looks like this:

```
public class FilteredKeyManager implements X509KeyManager {

    private final X509KeyManager originatingKeyManager;

    public FilteredKeyManager(X509KeyManager originatingKeyManager) {
        this.originatingKeyManager = originatingKeyManager;
    }

    @Override
    public String chooseClientAlias(String[] arg0, Principal[] arg1, Socket arg2) {
        return "yourAliasHere";
    }
}
```

For the rest of the overriden methods, just call the originatingKeyManager.

To create the SSLContext, I'm not using the SSLConfigurator, but the parameters are the same (path and password).

```
// Init keystore
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
FileInputStream ksFile = new FileInputStream("yourKeystorePath");
ks.load(ksFile, "keystorePassword".toCharArray());
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(ks, pass);

// Init truststore
KeyStore trustKeystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS"));
FileInputStream tsFile = new FileInputStream("yourTruststorePath"));
trustKeystore.load(tsFile, "truststorePassword".toCharArray());
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(trustKeystore);

// Create instance of custom KeyManager
KeyManager[] km = new KeyManager[] { new FilteredKeyManager((X509KeyManager) kmf.getKeyManagers()[0]) };

// Create SSLContext using custom KeyManager
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
context.init(km, ts, new SecureRandom());
```